# jQuery functions returning promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have an object (a Floor Area for reference) that belongs to a Category, the Category belongs to a Type. When adding a new object the user can choose an existing, or new, Type and Category. If the Category and/or Type don't exist a new one should be created.

For the UI I have two dropdown lists, Type and Categories, as well as the properties for the object. These dropdowns can also have new entries added (using select2). When selecting an existing Type, the Categories dropdown repopulates with the Categories for that Type.

If an existing Type is selected we should use the existing typeId from the dropdown list. If it's a new type we make a request to create a new Type and return the new typeId. Then we do the same for Categories. The categoryId is then used to create a new object.

I know in essence what I need to do to achieve this. In practice I'm struggling a bit with how to format the functions and promises in what they will return. I can get it working if both Type and Category already exist (code below). And with some changes, get it working if both Type and Category don't exist, but not both. I know it's something to do with the way I'm structuring my return types as functions.

`typeIdGet` should return either the existing or new typeId, instead it returns an Id if it is existing, but a `getJSON` function if it doesn't.

`categoryIdGet` should do the same but take the previously returned typeId if a new Category is required.

How do I structure the two typeIdGet functions to return an Id in either case?

How do I structure the two categoryIdGet functions to take the returned typeId from the previous function and return an Id in either case?

```
<script>
// ... click event handler and some code to get the selected Type and Category ...

// code below handles the promises

var myTypeId, myCategoryId;

if (existingType) { // existing type, return the selected Id
    typeIdGet = $.when(Number(selectedTypeId)); // this is a promise that resolves immediately
} else { // new Type we need to create one and get the new Id
    typeIdGet = $.getJSON(
        "Dimensions/Create?handler=NewType",
        {
            floorAreaTypeName: selectedTypeOption.text()
        },
        function (response) { // returns new Id
            return Number(JSON.parse(response));
        }
    );
}

if (existingCategory) {
    categoryIdGet = $.when(Number(selectedCategoryId));
} else {
    categoryIdGet = $.getJSON(
        "Dimensions/Create?handler=NewCategory",
        {
            floorAreaTypeId: myTypeId, // this should be passed in
            floorAreaCategoryName: selectedCategoryOption.text()
        },
        function (response) { // returns new Id
            return Number(JSON.parse(response));
        }
    );
}

typeIdGet.then(function (typeId) {
    myTypeId = typeId;
    return categoryIdGet; // Can we not pass in the typeId here?
}).then(function (categoryId) {
    myCategoryId = categoryId;
    alert("myTypeId: " + myTypeId + " myCategoryId:" + myCategoryId);
    // Create new floor area here with the categoryId
}).fail("Something went wrong");

</script>
```

Comment: not sure what your question is, based on the comments at the bottom of the code, something like `Promise.all([typeIdGet, categoryIdGet]).then(function ([typeId, categoryId]) {
    alert("myTypeId: " + typeId + " myCategoryId:" + categoryId);
})` - or using jQueries $.when ... ``$.when(typeIdGet, categoryIdGet).then(function (typeId, categoryId) {
    alert("myTypeId: " + typeId + " myCategoryId:" + categoryId);
})``

Comment: I thought `$.when(typeIdGet, categoryIdGet)` would runs these in parallel. `typeIdGet` needs to run first. Also when the typeId does not exist, and typeIdGet is set to the `$getJSON` it does not return an Id, it returns the whole `$getJSON` function and I have to pull out the result.

Comment: Have edited my question to actually have some questions, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that (as hinted at in your later comment), they two `$.getJSON` commands *are* running in parallel, because you didn't do anything to wait for the first one to finish before running the second one.

The easiest way to make that happen is to wrap them in functions (and make the functions always return a promise to make them easier to deal with:

```
function typeIdGet() {
  if ( existingType ) return Promise.resolve( Number( selectedTypeId ) );
  return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
    $.getJSON( `Dimensions/Create?handler=NewType`, {
      floorAreaTypeName : selectedTypeOption.text(),
    }, function( response ) {
      resolve( Number( JSON.parse( response ) ) );
    }
  } );
}

function categoryIdGet( typeId ) {
  if ( existingCategory ) return Promise.resolve( Number( selectedCategoryId ) );
  return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
    $.getJSON( 'Dimensions/Create?handler=NewCategory', {
      floorAreaTypeId : typeId.
      floorAreaCategoryName : selectedCategoryOption.text(),
    }, function( response ) {
      resolve( Number( JSON.parse( response ) ) );
    } );
  } );
}
```

Now, with that you can run them in the order you want:

```
typeIdGet().then( function( typeId ) {
  return categoryIdGet( typeId ).then( function( categoryId ) {
    console.log( "typeId:", typeId, "categoryId:", categoryId );
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that $.getJSON did return a promise already? Also in the final step to run them in order, I thought the whole idea of promises was that you didn't want to have to nest things, and so you could chain `.then` to keep the code tidy?

Comment: Wrapping `$.getJSON` in `new Promise` is an anti-pattern since it already returns a promise